# issues creating a table from a select statement mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a new `MySQL` from a `SELECT` statement:

```
   CREATE TABLE site_database AS(SELECT database_id, name, description, site_id FROM sitematrix_databases INNER JOIN site
    matrix_site_databases ON sitematrix_site_databases.database_id = sitematrix_data
    bases.database_id);
```

When I execute the `SELECT` statement, I get:

```
+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| database_id | name   | description | database_id | site_id |
+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+---------+
|           5 | tc2007 |             |           5 |       1 |
|           5 | tc2007 |             |           5 |       8 |
|           5 | tc2007 |             |           5 |       9 |
|           5 | tc2007 |             |           5 |      12 |
|           5 | tc2007 |             |           5 |      14 |
+-------------+--------+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

However, when I try to create the table, I get:

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'database_id' in field list is ambiguous
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Change `database_id` to `<table_name>.database_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your select statement make sure you specify which table the database id comes from:

```
CREATE TABLE site_database AS(SELECT sitematrix_site_databases.database_id, name, description, site_id FROM sitematrix_databases INNER JOIN site
    matrix_site_databases ON sitematrix_site_databases.database_id = sitematrix_data
    bases.database_id);
```

Would work, mysql requires this when more than one table have the same field names.

You could simplify it as thus:

```
CREATE TABLE site_database AS(SELECT ssd.database_id, name, description, site_id 
FROM sitematrix_databases as sd 
INNER JOIN sitematrix_site_databases as ssd 
ON ssd.database_id = sd.database_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the query to:

```
CREATE TABLE site_database AS(SELECT sitematrix_site_databases.database_id, name, description, site_id FROM sitematrix_databases  INNER JOIN site 
    matrix_site_databases ON sitematrix_site_databases.database_id = sitematrix_data
    bases.database_id);
```

as the field database_id appears in both tables: `sitematrix_databases` and in `site` hence the ambiguity